# learning locker queryStatement using timestamp as a filter

Tags: php, tin-can-api, lrs, learning-locker

I'm trying to query on statements stored in Learning Locker using TinCanPHP but I want to retrieve only the statements generated in a specific interval of time. For example, I want all the statements generated today.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$LRSResponse = $LRS->queryStatements(['since' => '2016-11-15', 'ascending' => false]); // change to 'true', or omit, for ascending dates
$StatementsResult = $LRSResponse->content;
$array_of_Statement_objects = $StatementsResult->getStatements();
foreach ($array_of_Statement_objects as $extracted_Statement_object){
// deal with statements as necessary
}
unset($extracted_Statement_object);
```

Comment: To limit to a single day (not today) you would have to also include the `until` parameter, and there shouldn't be a reason to include the `ascending` flag unless you want them in that order. Note that this is the `stored` order of the statements *not* the `timestamp` order.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but the time has to be indicated in the same format as the timestamp. It would be 

`$LRSResponse = $lrs->queryStatements(['since' => '2016-11-14T20:19:08+01:00', 'ascending' => false]);`